# viewDidLoad not called

Tags: ios6, uiviewcontroller, viewdidload

Everything is in the storyboard using pretty standard layout.
[image: Storyboard picture]

`UISplitViewController` with a detail view controller of `UINavigationController` which loads up my custom `UITableViewController`. Only the `viewDidLoad` in the custom `UITableViewController` never fires.

`viewWillAppear` fires as expected and everything else works perfectly. The view clearly is loaded (the only thing not working is the notifications I setup in `viewDidLoad`), by where is my callback?

My `viewDidLoad` method... 
[image: viewDidLoad code]
Breakpoint, `NSLog`... there is no way these things wouldn't give me feedback if this method executed.

Comment: What happens if you connect the detail view controller directly to the UITableVC. Does viewDidLoad in UITableVC fire?

Comment: I just pulled out the `UINavigationController` and it no effect on the `viewDidLoad` issue.

Comment: This looks like a custom TableView. Did you subclass TableView, replacing the default tableview and then changed the class in IB for TableView and UITableVC and made sure the UITableVC to TableView connections are correct. And if they are, I would recommend breaking the connections, do a project clean and reconnecting Table VC to views.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried re-creating my storyboard by creating a new project using a the Split View template. Then copying in all the appropriate View Controllers. It worked as expected. (`viewDidLoad` called normally).

I compared all my IB connections between the projects side by side... no difference. I then took my original project and deleted all the connections one by one then re-connented them (to the exact same thing they had been connected to). When I got done, I ran the code and everything worked. `viewDidLoad` called.

I tried doing a diff between the non-working storyboard version and working one because nothing should have been different, but obviously something was. I couldn't make heads or tails of it Even though much of the XML was identical, many bits were different parts of the XML file which made standard diff unrealistic. It was more like a jigsaw puzzle of trying to find where the bits matched each other and I gave up after an hour of finding nothing.

So a horribly unsatisifying answer. It was IB related, most likely outlets (but I did re-type class names and stuff too.. again identical). Most likely it was my error and not Xcode's, but it doesn't look like I'll be able to pin the exact reason.

*Thanks for suggestions, they helped me look in various directions which lead to the solution.*

Comment: I'm experiencing this too. I'm still trying to track down the issue but first signs point to the MediaPlayer framework. I have just a single standard view controller at the root of the storyboard - an Xcode Single View application template (for iPad). I added one View subclass that depends upon MediaPlayer and MobileCoreServices and suddenly viewDidLoad is not called on the root view controller class. I removed both frameworks and the dependencies and viewDidLoad was called. Tried adding MobileCoreServices alone, no trouble. Tried adding MediaPlayer and the problem reappeared. Testing on sim.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what "frameworks and the dependencies" fully entails. Framework should have no bearing. Adding in the `import` statements from the framework shouldn't matter. What is changes? If you you are swapping out "parents" of view controllers, make sure each class up the chain remembers to call `[super viewDidLoad];`

Comment: My answer is not specifically a solution to your problem, but a solution to the problem of viewDidLoad not being called. Your situation may have been very different. I probably should have put my comments on the question instead of this answer. In any case, by frameworks I mean things like MediaPlayer.framework, AudioToolbox.framework. When you add those to your project their classes and methods are added to your compiled product. By dependencies I just meant the code in my project that relied upon them (so I could compile).

Comment: The same thing happened to me twice now for a project I'm working on. Same solution as you worked for me: delete segues, recreate them and it works. Why? I have no idea either. Actually, the only thing I can think of is that I refactored some class names, although not the names of the view controllers that stopped loading. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are expecting `viewDidLoad` to be called when it was already loaded and just updated perhaps from the master view controller. In this case it would not have to be reloaded from the nib/storyboard and thus `viewDidLoad` would not be called.

Put a log statement into `viewDidLoad` and you will see that it is called at least once.

Comment: I have both an `NSLog` and a breakpoint set in the `viewDidLoad` method. It is never called. 'initWithCoder' is called, 'viewWillAppear' gets called, but 'viewDidLoad' just doesn't happen.

Comment: From the documentation: "*This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method.*" Maybe you are having several similar VC in your project and are mixing them up?

Comment: Doubtful since I only have 3 custom view controllers. `MasterViewController`, `DetailViewController` and `AttachmentViewController`. This thing is pretty much the Split View Template with the default `DetailViewController` turned into a `UITableViewController` the last one is just a segue on cell taps. I guess I'll try re-creating the template and dropping my classes in and see what happens.

Comment: Are you maybe calling `loadView` somewhere directly? That prevents the call to `loadView` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the name of your view controller subclass is not colliding with another class.

In my case I absentmindedly retained the auto-generated project class prefix of 'MP' and thus the project's root view controller subclass was MPViewController.

MPViewController is not documented anywhere, but because the problem occurred only when linking against the MediaPlayer framework it's probably a safe bet that it's defined somewhere and when the Storyboard was loaded the app created an instance of it instead of an instance of my custom class.

Answer (score 1):

You've probably created Storyboard file after the creation of the project. If so, you should've deleted the strings from AppDelegate.m file:

<strike>self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];</strike>

<strike>self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];</strike>

<strike>[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];</strike>